# Dynamically determine header based on GET parameters

Tags: rest, http-headers, soapui

For one of our `REST` webservices, we have implemented a `GET` method having the following URI:

```
http://ourcompany.com/doSomething/getSomething?parameter1=ABC&parameter2=123
```

Now, one of the **headers** required for security is the following

`userName: ABC123`, derived from concatenating the values of `parameter1` and `parameter2`

My question is, how, in SoapUI (preferably via the SoapUI interface, itself), do I dynamically generate this header value from the parameter values supplied in the `GET` method?

Comment: Question lacks clarity. How many steps does the test case has? Do you need to retrieve the values from previous step?

Comment: Sorry if its not clear. The test case has only 1 step. The header value has to be dynamically constructed from the GET request parameters

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I am kind of got you this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create test case level custom properties instead of string value for the parameters which you have currently, say

- name as `PROPERTY1`, and value as `ABC`
- name as `PROPERTY2`, and value as `123`

In the `GET` request step, provide values as *Property Expansion*, say
`${#TestCase#PROPERTY1}, ${#TestCase#PROPERTY2}` respectively for the parameters.

Coming to the headers, define the required header and use *Property Expansion* again. i.e., header name as `userName` and value as `${#TestCase#PROPERTY1}${#TestCase#PROPERTY2}`

Hope the above should resolve the issue.